# How to access elements in a multi value array swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an array:

```
var array: [[(playerPosition: CGPoint, playerName: String, enemy: SKSpriteNode, enemyName: String)]] = []
```

I then add to the array like this:

```
array.append([(playerPosition: player.position, playerName: player.name!, enemy: node as! SKSpriteNode, enemyName: enemy.name!)])
```

I then want to use these values later in sequence so I can change the players position/name and the enemy details/name:

```
player.position = //array's playerPosition
player.name = //array's PlayerName
enemy.name = //arrays enemyName
```

etc etc

How do I get access these different values?

Comment: How do you know which playerPosition to fetch?

Comment: I want to change the players position with the first index of the playerPosition in the array. Or that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Looking into it. Thanks Joakim.

Comment: Hi Joakim. The link you posted answered my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First it's better to mnake it a model like

```
struct Item {
   playerPosition: CGPoint
   ....
}
```

====

Then

```
var array: [[Item]]
```

===

and finally

```
player.position = array.map { $0.playerPosition }
```

Comment: Looking at this now!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get the `player` at first position from the `array`, you can use

```
if let player = array.first?.first {
    let position = player.playerPosition
    let name = player.playerName
    let enemy = player.enemyName
}
```